# How to get real position in space of the entity in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I have tried multiple ways to get the position of the element immediately after animation but every time I am receiving a hard-coded position of the entity that I have entered. I have used tick function to track the object all the time. These are the following ways I have tried to keep a track of current location of the entity but of them are returning a position that I have assigned to the entity. Is it a bug in aframe 1.2.0 because in previous versions its working fine.

```
Object.values(el.getAttribute('position'))
el.object3D.animations
Object.values(document.querySelector('#duck1').object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()))
Object.values(el.object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()))
```

For the reference I have atttached the live code as well. Right after mouseenters into cube the animation will trigger. After the end of animation location of the entity will be shown in `console.log` entry

The Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('eventhandling', {
            tick: function () {
                var el = this.el;
              var entity = document.querySelector('#duck1');
                el.addEventListener('animationcomplete', function(){
                    console.log("getAttribute: "+Object.values(el.getAttribute('position')));
                  console.log("object3D.position: "+(el.object3D.animations));
                  console.log("document.querySelector: "+ Object.values(document.querySelector('#duck1').object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3())));
                  console.log("object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()): "+Object.values(el.object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3())));
                   entity.emit('starteventforAnimation'); 
                });
          }
        });
    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
<a-entity class="rota" id="duck1" color="#FF0000" scale="0.1 0.1 .1" position="2 0 -7" animation="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:30000; pauseEvents: mouseenter; resumeEvents: starteventforAnimation " animation__mouseenter="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 360 0; easing:linear; dur:4000; startEvents: mouseenter ;pauseEvents: starteventforAnimation; resumeEvents: mouseenter" eventhandling>
            <a-box class="rota" color="#FF0000" gltf-model="spaceship.glb"  position="20 0 -10"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-box>
        </a-entity>
<a-camera position="0 1.2 1.3"><a-cursor objects=".rota" ></a-cursor></a-camera>        <

    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the listeners shouldn't be in `tick`, You're adding a new one on each render loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something called "world position".

The sphere is always at the same position regarding the box. The rotation of the box causes the sphere to move because the entire frame of reference is rotating. Its local position stays the same, but its world position is changing.

One way of getting the world position would be:

```
// local position
this.el.getAttribute("position");

// grab the reference to the underlaying object
const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
// or const mesh = this.el.object3D; 

// create a vector where the position will be copied to
const worldpos = new THREE.Vector3();

// get the world position - it's in the worldpos vector
mesh.getWorldPosition(worldpos);
```

---

Like i did here:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // i'll keep the local position here
      this.localpos = new THREE.Vector3();
      // I'll keep the world position here
      this.worldpos = new THREE.Vector3();
      // this is the reference to the <p> element
      this.textEl = document.querySelector("p")
    },
    // utility function
    posToString: function(pos) {
      return pos.x.toFixed(2) + " " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + " " + pos.z.toFixed(2);
    },
    // called on each frame
    tick: function() {
      // getAttribute("position") has the local position
      // this.el.object3D.position has the local position
      // this.el.getObject3D("mesh").position has the local position
      this.localpos.copy(this.el.getAttribute("position"))
      this.el.getObject3D("mesh").getWorldPosition(this.worldpos)

      // compose the displayed message
      let msg = "";
      msg += "Sphere local position:" + this.posToString(this.localpos)
      msg += "<br>"
      msg += "Sphere world position:" + this.posToString(this.worldpos)
      this.textEl.innerHTML = msg
    }
  })
</script>
<p style="position: fixed; z-index: 999;"></p>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="0 1 -4" color="blue" 
         animation="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:3000">
    <a-sphere position="2 0 0" color="green" radius="0.25" foo></a-sphere>
  </a-box>
</a-scene>
```